# facebook developer apps - cannot find page

Tags: facebook

when I try to create the "like" app for my website,it says that it cannot find the page.
I even copied and pasted my name to it. I want to be able to post from it and it will show up on my website. http:/facebook.com/thevisalusbody is what I am trying to get an app for

Answer (score 1):

You can't create like buttons for user pages.  You would have to convert your user profile to a fan page using [Facebook's tool](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php?migrate).